# Session variables seem not to be saved

Tags: php, session, time

Quite simple code:

```
<?
session_start();
$_SESSION['t'.time()]     = "ok";
echo "<pre>".print_r($_SESSION, 1)."</pre>";
?>
```

shows, as expected, something like

```
Array
(
    [t1330966834] => ok
    [t1330966835] => ok
    [t1330966836] => ok
)
```

after 3page reloads.

Let's change a few symbols:

```
$_SESSION[time()]     = "ok";
```

(now without 't') and I expect after few reloads something like

```
Array
(
    [t1330966834] => ok
    [t1330966835] => ok
    [t1330966836] => ok
    [1330967020] => ok
    [1330967021] => ok
    [1330967022] => ok
    [1330967023] => ok
)
```

But actually the result is absolutely different:

```
   Array
    (
        [t1330966834] => ok
        [t1330966835] => ok
        [t1330966836] => ok
        [1330967020] => ok
    )
```

We have 3 previous array cells ad one and only one 'time' cell - no matter how many times you reload the page. The time is correct, it different each second but only one cell without 't'!
Also I tried

```
$t =time();
$_SESSION[$t]     = "ok";
```

and even

```
$t =intval(time());
$_SESSION[$t]     = "ok";
```

But it's remains only one cell with time.

Tested at php 5.2.13 and 5.3.10 at 2 different servers.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try assigning both `$_SESSION['t'.time()] = 'ok'; $_SESSION[time()] = 'ok'` and see what happens. If the `t` versions keep showing up and the baretime version don't, then something weird is going on.

Comment: I don't know enough about the oddities of PHP session variables to answer this question, but when you take out the `t` it becomes a numeric index instead of a string index. Perhaps PHP only stores one numeric index in the session variables or something? Not sure, but it seems like this has something to do with it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The keys in the `$_SESSION` associative array are subject to the same limitations as regular variable names in PHP, i.e. they cannot start with a number and must start with a letter or underscore. For more details see the section on variables in this manual.

http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php

Answer (score 5):

When cranking error_reporting way up, you should notice this:

> Notice in <file>, line ...: `session_write_close()`: Skipping numeric key 1330967020

Numeric indeces to session variables are [not supported](http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php).

Answer (score 2):

This is **not a strange** thing. It is simply skipping numeric keys. You can see this error, if you have enabled the notice to be displayed.

As mentioned on [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.session.php#77438) comment on php.net. You should not use numeric keys to define values in session.

Quote

> Careful not to try to use integer as a key to the $_SESSION array (such as $_SESSION[0] = 1;)  or you will get the error "Notice: Unknown: Skipping numeric key 0. in Unknown on line 0"

Answer (score 1):

If you set `session.serialize-handler=php_serialize` in php.ini, you
can save numeric indexes in $_SESSION
https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.serialize-handler